# Install NuGet package with .NET CORE and visual studio code failed

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, .net-core, nuget

I am on ubuntu and I use VSCode and .NET CORE,
I installed a package called Otter with the command panel.

My .csproj is now like this :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Otter" Version="0.9.8.926"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

My main .cs file is :

```
using System;
using Otter;

namespace helloWorldFromCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to build my project with :

```
dotnet build
```

I receive this error :

```
Program.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Otter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/erwan/Documents/helloWorldFromCSharp/helloWorldFromCSharp.csproj]
```

I don"t know how to fix it.

Comment: Try to use `dotnet restore` before the build. To check if the dependency is well installed.

Comment: Done but i've the same error

Comment: I see that Otter last update is from april 2016. Is Otter available in .net Core? Or is it .net framework?

Comment: It seems not to be available in .NET CORE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with a simple .Net Core App to reproduce the problem. I have the same issue.

Otter is in .Net Framework 4.5, so It won't work with an Asp.Net Core Application.

Since you are on Ubuntu, you can't just switch to Asp.Net MVC. I recommend you to look for another 2d framework wrote in .Net Core or in .Net Standard (don't know if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `Otter.csproj`:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Meaning, you can't reference it from a project that compiles to `netcoreapp2.1`

You might want to clone the project and try to target it to a suitable framework version, if possible.

Comment: So I just need to fork the project and change the target framework version ?

Comment: Well, you can try but I don't think it will be that easy.